# How to hook according WMI function in fastprox.dll?

Tags: hook, detours

Below is a block of C# code , I want to hook (ms-detours) the enumerating part:

```
var wql=new WqlObjectQuery(queryString);
using(var searcher =new ManagementObjectSearcher(scope,wql))
{
  using(var records=searcher.Get())
  {
   **foreach(var record in records)** //This is where I want to hook
   {
   //do something
   }
  }
}
```

I don't know which function in fastprox.dll is the one to hook.
I've tried ?Get@CWbemObject@@UEAAJPEBGJPEAUtagVARIANT@@PEAJ2@Z , it could be hooked ,while it is not the one to enumerate ojbect.
Could anyone help ?

Comment: or hook .Get() ?

Comment: I'm answering my question myself. It's possible to hook ManagementObjectSearch.Get() by using MS-Detours. Below code is what I use , it could print the searching SQL. By digging into https://referencesource.microsoft.com/ , from the source code of ManagementObjectSearcher.Get() , I found the clue. 
`

TrueExecQueryWmi = (PWMINet_Util_ExecQueryWmi)DetourFindFunction("WMINet_Utils.dll", "ExecQueryWmi");
TrueWMINet_Util_Next = (PWMINet_Util_Next)DetourFindFunction("WMINet_Utils.dll", "Next");
`

Comment: However , Even I modified the returned pointer to pointer, the returned *IEnumWbemClassObject points to my implemented class . When Next() is called , I pass by my Implemented IWbemClassObject . The foreach instruction doesN't call the IWbemClassObject::Get() or IWbemClassObject::Next() , I don't know why. The only method called of my implemented IWbemClassObject is QueryInterface().
I confused